# How to set ruler with decimals in .vimrc file?

Tags: vimrc, ruler

I have this line in `.vimrc` file

```
set ruler
```

which shows the percentage of current line. But for very large text files, it would just show `0%` for first couple hundreds of lines, which is not quite useful. How can I `set ruler` such that is would show, for example, `0.04%`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd probably need to put your own code in the statusline to do it. For reference, this is the "default" with `'ruler'` set: `:set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution is to do the calculation by yourself and add them in your status line:

First you will need a function which returns as a string your current position as a decimal percentage:

```
function! GetCurrentPosition()
    return printf('%.2f%%', ( 100.0 * line('.') / line('$') ))
endfunction
```

The function uses `line('.')` to get the position of the cursor and `line('$')` to get the total number of lines in the buffer. If also uses `printf()` to convert the result to a string, keeping only 2 decimal numbers and using `%%` to add a literal percent sign.

Then you can add the result of this function to your statusline like this:

```
set statusline+=%{GetCurrentPosition()}
```

And you should get your desired result:

[image]